# Script error with sitecore 6.5 + .NET 4.5 on IIS7.5

Tags: telerik, iis-7.5, sitecore, .net-4.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am running into an issue with 4.5 and Sitecore 6.5.
We are currently using Sitecore.NET 6.5.0 (rev. 120706) on  .NET Framework 3.5 along with relevant Telerik controls and AJAXToolkit.

We are trying to migrate the .NET Framework to 4.5.2 now (and plan Sitecore migration little later).
Along with 4.5.2 Framework, we also tried to use latest versions of AjaxToolKit and Telerik.

While testing, we observed an issue that is affecting two behaviors.
1. The PageMethods to Web/Script Methods on server-side are failing. 
  On research, we found out that the GetTestMethod call on page www.MYWEBSITE.com/Feature/Page1.aspx is going to /Feature/Page1.aspx/GetTestMethod instead of /layouts/WebSite1/General/BasePage.aspx/GetTestMethod.

BasePage.aspx is the base page. PageMethods.get_page() is returning BasePage.aspx instead of /layouts/WebSite1/General/BasePage.aspx

2. The Telerik controls (like RadTreeView) on WEBSITE/Feature/Page1.aspx are throwing scripting errors saying 'Telerik is not defined'.
   Page1.aspx is a page inside Features Item under the home page in Sitecore.
   But if we use a classic asp.net page (TestTelerik.aspx) under the web site's main folder (not in sitecore), the telerik control works normally.

So, it looks like ItemResolver, IgnoreURlPrefixes, or something else in the configs is causing this issue.

Do I need to change something in the configs for Sitecore to handle this correctly.

My web.config is like below

<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="/sitecore/default.aspx|/trace.axd|/webresource.axd|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/applications/content manager/telerik.web.ui.dialoghandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd|/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd|/sitecore/admin/upgrade/|/layouts/testing|" />

.....

<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
<system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2">
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2014.1.403.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121FAE78165BA3D4"/>
        </assemblies>
      </compilation>
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>

      </authorization>

    </system.web>

  </location>

.....
<system.web>


    <webServices>

      <protocols>

        <add name="HttpGet" />

        <add name="HttpPost" />

      </protocols>

    </webServices>

    <!-- Continue to run Sitecore without script validations -->

    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">

      <controls>

        <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" />

        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>

        <add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />

        <add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Analytics" />

      </controls>

    </pages>

    <httpModules>

      <add type="Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule,Sitecore.Nexus" name="SitecoreHttpModule" />

      <add type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.UploadWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreUploadWatcher" />

      <add type="Sitecore.IO.XslWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreXslWatcher" />

      <add type="Sitecore.IO.LayoutWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreLayoutWatcher" />

      <add type="Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreConfigWatcher" />

      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

      <add type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Kernel" name="MediaRequestSessionModule" />

      <add type="Sitecore.Web.HttpModule,Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreHttpModuleExtensions" />

    </httpModules>

    <httpHandlers>

      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_webDAV.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.WebDAVMediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" />
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" />

      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_xaml.ashx" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XamlSharp.Xaml.XamlPageHandlerFactory, Sitecore.Kernel" />
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_icon.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.IconRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" />

      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_feed.ashx" type="Sitecore.Shell.Feeds.FeedRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" />
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_handlers.ashx" type="Sitecore.Web.CustomHandlerFactory, Sitecore.Kernel" />

      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />

      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"  />

           <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" verb="*" validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" verb="*" validate="false"/>

      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" verb="*" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
......
<system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule" />
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <add type="Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule,Sitecore.Nexus" name="SitecoreHttpModule" />
      <add type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.UploadWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreUploadWatcher" />
      <add type="Sitecore.IO.XslWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreXslWatcher" />
      <add type="Sitecore.IO.LayoutWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreLayoutWatcher" />
      <add type="Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreConfigWatcher" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
      <add type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Kernel" name="MediaRequestSessionModule" />
      <remove name="Detector" />
      <add type="Sitecore.Web.HttpModule,Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreHttpModuleExtensions" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
      <remove name="ScriptResource" />
      <remove name="WebDAVRoot"/>
      <remove name="WebDAVRoot64"/>
      <add modules="IsapiModule" name="WebDAVRoot64" path="*" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" resourceType="Unspecified" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" verb="*">
</add>
      <add modules="IsapiModule" name="WebDAVRoot" path="*" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" resourceType="Unspecified" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" verb="*">
</add>
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_webDAV.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.WebDAVMediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" name="Sitecore.WebDAVMediaRequestHandler" />

      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler" />
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_xaml.ashx" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.XamlSharp.Xaml.XamlPageHandlerFactory, Sitecore.Kernel" name="Sitecore.XamlPageRequestHandler" />

      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_icon.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.IconRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" name="Sitecore.IconRequestHandler" />
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_feed.ashx" type="Sitecore.Shell.Feeds.FeedRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" name="Sitecore.FeedRequestHandler" />

      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_handlers.ashx" type="Sitecore.Web.CustomHandlerFactory, Sitecore.Kernel" name="Sitecore.GenericHandler" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd"/>
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx"/>
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>

      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    < /handlers> 
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <system.webServer>

PS: On migrating 3.5 to 4.5.2...the Visual Studio 2013 removed the 3.5 specific references to System.Web.Extensions and other stuff. I added some references to System.Web.Extensions manually (as observed above).

Answer (score 0):

Before you get to far into trying to make Sitecore 6.5 work with .NET 4.5 please check the Sitecore Compatibility chart located here -> https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164.

.NET 4.5 is only supported in Sitecore 6.5 Update 5 and newer.  You can review this KB article for more info -> https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/627179

Comment: Thank you for the response and useful references. I did ran through the above links and made sure that .NET 4.5 is compatible for the Sitecore we are using which is 6.5 update 5(120706). After couple of tweaks to web.config, I narrowed down the issue to "Sitecore not mapping the URLs correctly for AJAX calls" as PageMethods.get_page() is returning BasePage.aspx instead of /layouts/WebSite1/General/BasePage.aspx. If I set this path using PageMethods.set_page it works. But I do not want to set like this, as there are multiple base pages. So, I am researching for other better solutions.